# SQL Server: Getting NULL value when transposing rows to columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables `tblValuationSubGroup` & `tblValuationFieldValue`. i want to fetch field name from tblValuationSubGroup table and order field name value by FieldOrder field in table.

this table tblValuationFieldValue has field name and value too.

i want to show the value ticker, clientcode and Group name wise.

1. Field Order will be based on **FieldOrder column of tblValuationSubGroup table**.
2. records order will be based on **RecOrder column of tblValuationFieldValue table**.

There are 2 fields called `Last Update` & `Broker`. so they are coming as column header. in reality there would be more fields name for Ticker, clientcode & GroupName wise. so if there would be more value will be saved in `FieldName` column of two table `tblValuationSubGroup` & `tblValuationFieldValue` then those fields should come as a column header.

I am not very good in sql.
Here is my table schema & data.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblValuationFieldValue](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Ticker] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ClientCode] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [GroupName] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [FieldName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [FieldValue] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [RecOrder] [int] NULL,
    [InsertedOn] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblValuationSubGroup](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Ticker] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ClientCode] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [GroupName] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [FieldName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [FieldOrder] [int] NULL,
    [InsertedOn] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblValuationFieldValue] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblValuationFieldValue] ([ID], [Ticker], [ClientCode], [GroupName], [FieldName], [FieldValue], [RecOrder], [InsertedOn]) VALUES (1, N'G', N'SNFLD', N'Group1', N'Last Update', N'2021-08-14', 1, CAST(N'2021-08-14T04:50:46.270' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblValuationFieldValue] ([ID], [Ticker], [ClientCode], [GroupName], [FieldName], [FieldValue], [RecOrder], [InsertedOn]) VALUES (2, N'G', N'SNFLD', N'Group1', N'Broker', N'Barclays Capital', 2, CAST(N'2021-08-14T04:50:46.287' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblValuationFieldValue] ([ID], [Ticker], [ClientCode], [GroupName], [FieldName], [FieldValue], [RecOrder], [InsertedOn]) VALUES (3, N'G', N'SNFLD', N'Group2', N'EV / EBITDA', N'1.6x', 1, CAST(N'2021-08-14T04:50:46.290' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblValuationFieldValue] ([ID], [Ticker], [ClientCode], [GroupName], [FieldName], [FieldValue], [RecOrder], [InsertedOn]) VALUES (4, N'G', N'SNFLD', N'Group2', N'EV / Revenue', N'5.0x', 2, CAST(N'2021-08-14T04:50:46.290' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblValuationFieldValue] ([ID], [Ticker], [ClientCode], [GroupName], [FieldName], [FieldValue], [RecOrder], [InsertedOn]) VALUES (5, N'G', N'SNFLD', N'Group1', N'Last Update', N'2021-08-15', 1, CAST(N'2021-08-14T05:31:56.800' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblValuationFieldValue] ([ID], [Ticker], [ClientCode], [GroupName], [FieldName], [FieldValue], [RecOrder], [InsertedOn]) VALUES (6, N'G', N'SNFLD', N'Group1', N'Broker', N'Jeffry', 2, CAST(N'2021-08-14T05:31:56.800' AS DateTime))
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblValuationFieldValue] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblValuationSubGroup] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblValuationSubGroup] ([ID], [Ticker], [ClientCode], [GroupName], [FieldName], [FieldOrder], [InsertedOn]) VALUES (1, N'G', N'SNFLD', N'Group1', N'Last Update', 1, CAST(N'2021-08-13T07:02:31.890' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblValuationSubGroup] ([ID], [Ticker], [ClientCode], [GroupName], [FieldName], [FieldOrder], [InsertedOn]) VALUES (2, N'G', N'SNFLD', N'Group1', N'Broker', 2, CAST(N'2021-08-13T07:02:44.817' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblValuationSubGroup] ([ID], [Ticker], [ClientCode], [GroupName], [FieldName], [FieldOrder], [InsertedOn]) VALUES (6, N'G', N'SNFLD', N'Group2', N'EV / EBITDA', 1, CAST(N'2021-08-13T07:51:05.763' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblValuationSubGroup] ([ID], [Ticker], [ClientCode], [GroupName], [FieldName], [FieldOrder], [InsertedOn]) VALUES (4, N'G', N'SNFLD', N'Group2', N'EV / Revenue', 2, CAST(N'2021-08-13T07:03:33.990' AS DateTime))
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblValuationSubGroup] OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblValuationFieldValue] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblValuationFieldValue_InsertedOn]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [InsertedOn]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblValuationSubGroup] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblValuationSubGroup_InsertedOn]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [InsertedOn]
GO
```

This script i am trying which is not giving right output.

```
DECLARE @Ticker VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @ClientCode VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @GroupName VARCHAR(10)

SET @Ticker='G'
SET @ClientCode='SNFLD'
SET @GroupName='Group1'

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT f.ID,f.ticker,f.ClientCode,f.GroupName,' + STUFF((SELECT N',' + @CRLF + N'       ' +
                                      N'MAX(CASE FieldName WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(FieldName,'''') + N' THEN FieldValue END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(FieldName)
                               FROM tblValuationSubGroup g  
                               WHERE ticker=@Ticker AND ClientCode=@ClientCode AND GroupName=@GroupName
                               GROUP BY FieldName
                               ORDER BY MIN(FieldOrder)
                               FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,10,N'') + @CRLF +
           N'FROM tblValuationFieldValue f' + @CRLF +
           N'WHERE f.Ticker = '''+@Ticker+'''  AND f.ClientCode = '''+@ClientCode+''' AND f.GroupName='''+@GroupName+''' 
           GROUP BY f.ID,f.ticker,f.ClientCode,f.GroupName,f.RecOrder ORDER BY f.RecOrder'; 

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

screen shot where NULL is coming.

[image]

Expected output:

```
+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+-------------+------------------+
| ID     | Ticker |  ClientCode | GroupName |  Last Update|    Broker        |
+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+-------------+------------------+
| 1      | G      |    SNFLD    | Group1    | 2021-08-14  | Barclays Capital |
| 2      | G      |    SNFLD    | Group1    | 2021-08-15  | Jeffry           |
+--------+--------+-------------+-----------+-------------+------------------+
```

Comment: It's not related directly to your question, but why are do you have each `VALUES` as a discrete `INSERT` statement?

Comment: storing values in separate table called [tblValuationFieldValue]. this table has field name and value too.

Comment: I get that, but you do 10 individual inserts rather than the minimum of 2 that are needed.

Comment: insert are there for two different table. 4 rec inserted into [tblValuationSubGroup] table and 6 rec inserted into [tblValuationFieldValue] table.

Comment: A single `INSERT` statement can insert multiple rows `... VALUES (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c') ...;`

Comment: my issue is here not regarding how to insert multiple data into table using single insert. my issue is my sql return null value which is not desired one. so please review my code and tell me what to fix to get right output.

Comment: You probably want to include `InsertedOn` in your group by instead of `RecOrder`, but the insert times seem a little off, e.g.: `'2021-08-14T04:50:46.270'` != `'2021-08-14T04:50:46.287'`

Comment: i want to use RecOrder to order data instead of InsertedOn field

Comment: Ok, but grouping on the given `RecOrder` values are what causes your `FieldValues` to appear in alternate rows.

Comment: i removed RecOrder from here `GROUP BY f.ID,f.ticker,f.ClientCode,f.GroupName,f.RecOrder ORDER BY f.RecOrder';` but still getting wrong output.

Comment: I think the essential problem here is that there is no unique relationship between the `LastUpdate` record and the intended `Broker` record except that they have identical `InsertedOn` values - and that's a very brittle relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a cursor and something to help differentiate one group of data from others. I ended up with the following sql snippet:

```
DECLARE @Ticker VARCHAR(10) = N'G';
DECLARE @ClientCode VARCHAR(10) = N'SNFLD';
DECLARE @GroupName VARCHAR(10) = N'Group1';
DECLARE @FieldName VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
DECLARE @max NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
DECLARE @pfx_sql NVARCHAR(8) = N'      ';
DECLARE @pfx_max NVARCHAR(4) = N'  ';

DECLARE C CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
  SELECT FieldName
  FROM tblValuationSubGroup
  WHERE
    Ticker = @Ticker AND
    ClientCode = @ClientCode AND
    GroupName = @GroupName;

OPEN c;
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @FieldName;
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0 BEGIN
  SET @sql += @pfx_sql + N'CASE FieldName WHEN ''' +
              @FieldName + N''' THEN FieldValue END AS [' +
              @FieldName + N']';
  SET @pfx_sql = N',
      ';
  SET @max += @pfx_max + N'MAX([' + @FieldName + N']) AS [' +
              @FieldName + N']';
  SET @pfx_max = N',
  ';
  FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @FieldName;
END
CLOSE C;

SET @sql = N'WITH
  a AS (
    SELECT
      Ticker, ClientCode, GroupName,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RecOrder ORDER BY ID) AS grp,
' + @sql + N'
    FROM tblValuationFieldValue
    WHERE
      Ticker = @Ticker AND
      ClientCode = @ClientCode AND
      GroupName = @GroupName
  )
SELECT
  Ticker, ClientCode, GroupName,
' + @max + N'
FROM a
GROUP BY
  grp, Ticker, ClientCode, GroupName';

DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'@Ticker VARCHAR(10),
@ClientCode VARCHAR(10),
@GroupName VARCHAR(10)';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, @params,
  @Ticker = @Ticker, @ClientCode = @ClientCode, @GroupName = @GroupName;
```

Result:

```
+--------+------------+-----------+-------------+------------------+
| Ticker | ClientCode | GroupName | Last Update |      Broker      |
+--------+------------+-----------+-------------+------------------+
| G      | SNFLD      | Group1    | 2021-08-14  | Barclays Capital |
| G      | SNFLD      | Group1    | 2021-08-15  | Jeffry           |
+--------+------------+-----------+-------------+------------------+
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=f93f60431b79c86cbce08dc1d5e93285)